# Browser Settings/Capabilities Test Page

Tags: configuration, browser, testing

We have a client that says that our dhtml menus dont show up at all.  Are there any pages out there that test for browser configuration problems such as having javascript disabled, cookies disabled etc and advises user on how to fix issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://browsershots.org/ will allow you to test with a variety of browsers.  It also allows you to see javascript enabled/disabled (as well as multiple Javascript versions).  I don't believe that it will give you any help in the cookie department.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try http://browserspy.dk/